# Converting Eigen array to Eigen vector

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

Is there anything wrong with this? Eigen's documentation says its vectors are just matrices with one of the dimensions set to size 1. But I would prefer a `.vector()` method.

```
Eigen::VectorXd tmpVec(5);
tmpVec << 1,2,3,4,5;
Eigen::VectorXd result = tmpVec.array().matrix();
std::cout << result << "\n";
```

Comment: Well, this is a pretty unfortunate naming convention. I was pretty sure you just misspelled eigenvector until I read the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The methods `.array()` and `.matrix()` permits to change the semantic from matrix-linear-algebra to plain-array and vice-versa. So having both a `.vector()` and a `.matrix()` to describe the same change of semantic would be rather cumbersome.